# Solving a difference equation with initial condition

Tags: matlab

Consider a difference equation with its initial conditions.

```
5y(n) + y(n-1) - 3y(n-2) = (1/5^n) u(n), n>=0
y(n-1) = 2, y(n-2) = 0
```

How can I determine y(n) in Matlab?

Comment: Here is a function I have built to calculate it with added example.
[enter link description here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56142-output-estimation-difference-equation)

Comment: y(n-1) = 2, y(n-2) = 0  wont work (and doesn't make any sense). initial condition cannot have 'n' in it. You should specify initial condition like y(0) = some value, y(1) = some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an approach similar to [this](https://www.mathworks.se/matlabcentral/answers/81270) (using [`filter`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/filter.html)), but specifying initial conditions as done [here](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/answers/46755) (using [`filtic`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/filtic.html)).

I'm assuming your initial conditions are: `y(-1)=2`, `y(-2)=0`.

```
num = 1; %// numerator of transfer function (from difference equation)
den = [5 1 -3]; %// denominator of transfer function (from difference equation)
n = 0:100; %// choose as desired
x = (1/5).^n; %// n is >= 0, so u(n) is 1
y = filter(num, den, x, filtic(num, den, [2 0], [0 0]));
%// [2 0] reflects initial conditions on y, and [0 0] those on x.
```

Here's a plot of the result, obtained with `stem(n,y)`.

[image]

Comment: I like your approach with `filter`. But as commented on my answer, I don't believe you can just remove `u(n)`. Actually, from your point of view, `(1/5^n) u(n)` is what is being filtered, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The second line of your code does not give initial conditions, because it refers to the index variable `n`. Since Matlab only allows positive integer indices, I'll assume that you mean `y(1) = 0` and `y(2) = 2`.

You can get an iteration rule out of your first equation by simple algebra:

```
y(n) = ( (1/5^n) u(n) - y(n-1) + 3y(n-2) ) / 5
```

Code to apply this rule in Matlab:

```
n_max = 100;
y = nan(n_max, 1);
y(1) = 0;
y(2) = 2;
for n = 3 : n_max
  y(n) = ( (1/5^n) * u(n) - y(n-1) + 3 * y(n-2) ) / 5;
end
```

This code assumes that the array `u` is already defined. `n_max` specifies how many elements of `y` to compute.

Comment: You need to define (maybe just remove) `u(n)`. BTW, nice hat :-D

Comment: In addition to removing `u(n)` (because it equals 1 for all considered `n`), you should replace `1/5^n` by `1/5^(n-3)`. This is because your n=1 is really time instant -2; your n=2 is really -1 etc. That's assuming the initial conditions are y(-2), y(-1). With those corrections (do you agree?), your answer and mine give the same result

Comment: Not sure about the initial conditions and `1/5^n`, probably you're right. The initial conditions given by the OP didn't really make sense, so I changed them into something that does make sense, and you changed them into something else that also makes sense. – I disagree about `u(n)` though; how would you know it is equal 1? It wasn't explicitly defined by the OP, so one can just assume that it has been defined somewhere else.

Comment: In signal processing, `u(n)` usually denotes the [(discrete-time) step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form), which equals 1 for n>=0. Although of course it could be something else